# Update links between source and destination excel files

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I have a folder that contains one excel source file and two excel destination files. My objective is to create a macro that updates the links in the destination files whenever the user saves the source file. I need this macro to be executed even when the destination files are closed because the user only opens the source file.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following subroutine to a standard module in your source workbook:

```
Public Sub SaveDestinationFiles()
    Const N as Long = 2
    Dim strDest(1 To N) As String
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    ' Replace these with the actual shared drive & names of the destination folders & files
    strDest(1) = "D:\sharedfolder\dest1.xlsx"
    strDest(2) = "D:\sharedfolder\dest2.xlsx"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To N
        Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(strDest(i), UpdateLinks:=True)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            wbDest.Save
            wbDest.Close
        ElseIf Err.Number = 1004 Then
            ' Delete this next line if you don't want to show any warning message when the save fails.
            MsgBox "Could not update " & strDest(i) & ". Please follow up to ensure this file is kept current.", vbExclamation, "Warning"
        End If
        Err.Clear
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Then, add the following subroutine to the ThisWorkbook code module in your source workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    SaveDestinationFiles
End Sub
```

The first sub will simply open each destination workbook while allowing its links to update, save it, and close it--which should accomplish what you're looking to do. This happens without the user actually seeing those workbooks open, because of the lines with `Application.ScreenUpdating`.

The second sub is what makes the first sub fire automatically whenever someone saves the source workbook. This sub is an event procedure, so it's important not to change its name or arguments.

If the destination files are indeed in the same folder as the source file, then you can just put the filename as "whatever.xlsx". However, if they are in a different folder, then you should use the full name, e.g. "C:\otherfolder\whatever.xlsx" instead.

Finally, you can also easily extend the sub to add more destination files to be saved in the future, if you ever need to: for example, if you wanted to have 3 files, then change the first line to `Const N as Long = 3`, and add `strDest(3) = "dest3.xlsx"` where the filenames are.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a way to insert the code in an external vbscript file within my folder ? The user often shares solely the source file (not the entire folder) with a team and I am afraid they will have errors pop up whenever they hit save.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think so... I don't think the vbscript would have access to the Excel object model.

However, what *is* possible is to adjust the code with a little error-checking logic so that it *tries* to save the files, but simply stays quiet without displaying any error messages if it cannot find the destination files to update.

You can also display a MsgBox warning that the destination file was not updated, so that your user remembers to follow up via e-mail or follow a business process to keep the file current. I've edited the original answer to do this.

Comment: Also, if your users are in a company & the destination files are on a network shared drive somewhere: then you can use the absolute path to the destination files, and they will still update when the user saves the source from any folder, as long as he/she has write access to the folder the destination files are in.